# How to maximise UDP packets-per-second with Go?

Tags: go, networking, udp, load-testing

I'm trying to write a simple relay server in Go for the purposes of sending game data between two clients. The clients send UDP registration messages consisting of the protocol id followed by their match id and their client id; These messages are used to set up a hashmap of addresses to address so that when a standard (game-data) message arrives we can map it to it's pre-registered recipient (without having to send that data in each message). (I'm using [github.com/cornelk/hashmap](https://github.com/cornelk/hashmap) if that makes any difference and the server is a highcpu-16 GCP Compute instance)

This setup works fine with a low number of clients (~30 messages per second). However, as I ramp up the load testing the outgoing bandwidth levels off as incoming bandwidth continues to rise. I've done logging with [`vmstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vmstat.8.html) and [`ifstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifstat.8.html) (as well as some [`dropwatch`](https://github.com/nhorman/dropwatch) monitoring, which says lots of packets are being dropped at the software level). It looks to me like packets are being dropped because my go server isn't reading them quick enough.

Initially, I used one goroutine per cpu core:

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

connection, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
    go listen(connection, c)
}
```

I've also tried reusing the port and listening separately with each goroutine (using the [github.com/libp2p/go-reuseport](https://github.com/libp2p/go-reuseport) package).

Finally, I tried setting up buffered channels for incoming and outgoing messages, in an effort to minimise the time that the listening goroutines aren't pulling messages.

What am I missing in my attempt to handle 100K players at a time? It feels like no matter my approach I cannot surpass around 3000 players without losing a significant number of packets.

My `listen` function has gone through many iterations in vain attempts to get the packet-per-second up but it's generally:

```
// Emits SIGABRT to the interrupts channel if an error occurs outside of individual message handling.
func listen(connection *net.UDPConn, interrupts chan os.Signal/*, inbox chan IncomingMessage*/) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    n, remoteAddr, err := 0, new(net.UDPAddr), error(nil)
    for err == nil {
        n, remoteAddr, err = connection.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        //log.Println("Received", n, "bytes", hex.EncodeToString(buffer[:n]))
        if n < 2 {
            log.Println("Minimum packet length is 2 bytes. Received a packet of length", n, "bytes")
            continue
        }

        //inbox<-IncomingMessage{
        //    sender: remoteAddr,
        //    data:   append([]byte(nil), buffer[:n]...),
        //}

        //go handlePacket(inbox, remoteAddr, append([]byte(nil), buffer[:n]...), n)

        protocolId := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(buffer)
        if protocolId == registrationProtocolId {
            // Start a goroutine to handle the packet (copy the buffer minus the protocol id))
            //go handleRegistrationPacket(connection, remoteAddr, append([]byte(nil), buffer[:n]...))
            handleRegistrationPacket(outbox, remoteAddr, buffer[:n])
        } else if protocolId == matchProtocolId {
            //go handleStandardPacket(connection, remoteAddr.String(), append([]byte(nil), buffer[:n]...))
            handleStandardPacket(outbox, remoteAddr.String(), buffer[:n])
        } else {
            log.Println("Unrecognised protocol id: ", protocolId)
        }
    }
    log.Println("Listener failed:", err)
    interrupts<-syscall.SIGABRT
}
```

This graph shows 1600 concurrent games (3200 clients). Past a certain point, the outgoing KB/s stops climbing. The CPU isn't even breaking a sweat.
[image: Load-Test Graph showing Network bandwidth and cpu load]

Comment: There's a lot to improve here, but the 2 main issues are that you're processing _every_ message through a single 1024 byte buffer, which also means you can't make this concurrent at all, because you have a data race on every read and write. Secondly, you're blocking the read loop while handling the packets. You'll need to start with a synchronized pool of buffers, and handlers running asynchronously. Multiple readers may help, but you'll have to test that.

Comment: Is it not a buffer per goroutine?  
Toward the end of the day I did switch to using a channel and consumers for processing the messages, as well as increasing the networking limits on the machine via `sysctl`.  
This did remedy the issue a little, I'll have to test more on Monday and I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read [How to receive a million packets per second](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-receive-a-million-packets/), which suggests that using the `SO_REUSEPORT` option on the sockets is the right approach. In the code below, I'm using a connection per core of the machine (16 in my case) and 4 outbox handlers per connection. CPU use is a little higher with 4 per connection but it seems a little more reliable than 1 per connection (though testing and a definitive answer is needed).

Not shown below is that the `listen` function starts goroutines to handle the incoming messages and immediately returns to listening. The `outbox` is passed to the handling function as a means to send messages.

```
type OutgoingMessage struct {
    recipient *net.UDPAddr
    data      []byte
}

// ...

func beginListen(c chan os.Signal) {
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: 1234,
        IP:   net.IP{0, 0, 0, 0},
    }

    connection, err := reuseport.ListenPacket("udp", addr.String())

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    outbox := make(chan OutgoingMessage, maxQueueSize)

    sendFromOutbox := func() {
        n, err := 0, error(nil)
        for msg := range outbox {
            n, err = connection.(*net.UDPConn).WriteToUDP(msg.data, msg.recipient)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            if n != len(msg.data) {
                log.Println("Tried to send", len(msg.data), "bytes but only sent ", n)
            }
        }
    }

    for i := 1;  i <= 4; i++ {
        go sendFromOutbox()
    }

    listen(connection.(*net.UDPConn), c, outbox)

    close(outbox)
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting...")

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        go beginListen(c)
    }

    // ...
}
```

This graph below shows the difference from before:
[image: Graph showing bandwitch and cpu load]

(This has been a spike so far; The variable names won't stay, and I'm aware that I should continue to write unsent bytes until all data is sent.)

Comment: you do not have a working demo of this in Go on github or something ? i am a bit further behind you in trying to achieve almost the same but really struggle with performance in Go when it comes to UDP and my brain is twisting here and considering if its not worth the fight but instead go back to C++ ? did you end up getting it working ?

Comment: Unfortuneately, I did not make an open-source demo and have since moved on from the company that I wrote this for. It's unlikely that I'll have time to make a demo in the near to medium future.
I do, however, highly reccommend the blog post about how to receive a million packets a second: https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-receive-a-million-packets/